# Delete option for the dropped list item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I have used the following **HTML and Javascript** for drag and drop list items from one div to another div.

Html:

```
<div class="listArea">
   <h4> Drag and Drop list in Green Area: </h4>
   <ul class="unstyle">
      <li id="drag1" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 1
      </li>
      <li id="drag2" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 2 
      </li>
      <li id="drag3" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 3
      </li>
      <li id="drag4" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event)">
          i am list 4
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="buildArea" id="div1" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)">
   <h4> Drop Here </h4> 
</div>
```

And Typescript contains the following:

```
  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
  }
```

The stackblitz link was, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyimor

The thing i am in the need was after i have dropped the list item into the div with class `buildArea`, the list item can be deleted that is i am in the need to generate unique delete button for each dropped item and on click that button that current list has to be deleted.

The option for deleting the dropped list item in the green area from the given **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyimor)** needs to be done.
I am also required to use only **pure javascript** and jquery needs to be ignored.

After a long search i couldn't find out any solution regarding it and hence kindly help me to achieve the desire output of deleting the dropped list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/drag-and-drop-pronlem)

```
  <div class="listArea">
    <h4> Drag and Drop list in Green Area: </h4>
    <ul class="unstyle">
        <li *ngFor="let li of List; let i = index" id="drag{{i}}" draggable="true" (dragstart)="drag($event, i) ">
            i am list {{li.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


    <div class="buildArea " id="div1 " (drop)="drop($event) " (dragover)="allowDrop($event) ">
        <h4> Drop Here </h4>

        <ul class="unstyle">
            <li *ngFor="let li of DraggedList; let i = index" id="dragged{{i}}">
                <p>{{li.innerHTML}}</p>
                <button (click)="deleteItem(i)" type="button"> X</button>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
List: Array<any> = [
    { name: 1 },
    { name: 2 },
    { name: 3 },
    { name: 4 },
    { name: 5 },
  ]
  elId: number;

  DraggedList: Array<any> = [

  ]

  allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }

  drag(ev, i) {
    this.elId = i;
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  }

  drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    // ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
    this.DraggedList.push(document.getElementById(data));
  }

  deleteItem(i) {
    if (i > -1) {
      this.DraggedList.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your solution will work if i remove ```.cloneNode(true)``` from the line ```ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));``` in the code i have given for that why this much workaround? But the thing i am in the need is after dropping i have to make a delete option to delete the dropped list item in the green area.. There is nothing to do with the draggable items..

Comment: i have done because it can generate a unique id for each element dynamically. no need to specify for each. if you want to put button you can use than

Comment: Thats Okay, but i am in the need to delete only the dropped list that is all i want.. And also there is no need to remove the draggable items..

Comment: got it.. do you want to put delete button for each dragged item(available in green box)??

Comment: Yes but in drag list there is no need of any delete button, Only thing is after dropped into the green list the delete has to be done.. Scenario is user might have wrongly dropped the list so to delete it i am in the need of that option.

Comment: Yes this is what i am in the need, Thanks for your time.

Comment: welcome . if you have any doubt regarding that ping me back.

Comment: OKay, i will revert back to you if i have any doubts.